# Get the time from XML using AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, date, time

I have an XML file of various auction items that will display based on the time. I want to use AS3 to getUTCDate based on the hour set in the  field of the XML file and then display the appropriate XML node. I'm pretty much intermediate with AS3+XML so I could use some help. I've got everything setup but something isn't quite right.

AS3 Code:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sample_auction.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);


var my_date:Date = new Date();
var currentHour:Number = my_date.getUTCHours() + (my_date.getUTCMinutes() / 60);
trace(currentHour);


function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);
for(var i:uint = 0; i < xmlData.auction.length(); i++)
{   
    if(xmlData.auction[i].time < currentHour)
    {
    auctionName_txt.text = xmlData.auction[i].title;
    auctionDesc_txt.text = xmlData.auction[i].description;
    }
}

}
```

do I need to declare the various times from xml such as doing a var on each time or something? how can I get it so the AS3 knows that the time node is an actual time? Here is some sample XML code. (also I'm not calling the image yet I'm just trying to get this thing to read the appropriate nodes first.) It's not throwing a complier error but it's also not sure what to do yet.

The XML Code:

```
<auctionlist>
<auction>
<time>6:00</time>
<title>Example Auction 1</title>
<description>Placeholder Text blah blah.</description>
<image>sampleimage1.jpg</image>
</auction>


<auction>
<time>7:00</time>
<title>Example Auction 2</title>
<description>Placeholder text blbalblbladflknsdf</description>
<image>imagepath11.jpg</image>
</auction>


<auction>
<time>8:00</time>
<title>Sample Auction 3</title>
<description>Placeholder text asflkamdflkmasdfm</description>
<image>imagepath12.jpg</image>
</auction>


<auction>
<time>9:00</time>
<title>Sample Auction 4</title>
<description>Placeholder text blabjadsflkm afdlkmasf afmlksf mmasdflkm</description>
<image>imagepath12.jpg</image>
</auction>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ok based on the comments below, I now have this:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

flash.system.Security.allowDomain('*');

var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sample_auction.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);

var my_date:Date = new Date();
var currentHour:Number = my_date.getUTCHours() + (my_date.getUTCMinutes() / 60);
trace(currentHour);

function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);
for(var i:uint = 0; i < xmlData.auction.length(); i++)
{ 
var started:XMLList = xmlData.auction.(parseTime(time) >= currentHour);
for each (var item:XML in started)
{
    auctionName_txt.text = xmlData.auction[i].title;
    auctionDesc_txt.text = xmlData.auction[i].description;  
}       
}
}

function parseTime(time:String):Number {
var hour:int = time.split(":")[0];
var minute:int = time.split(":")[1];
return hour + minute / 60;
}
```

This returns the last node no matter what time I set my clock to. I can tell this is close but it seems to not restrict to the node time but just loop through to the end.

### UPDATED

Ok here is latest code - now produces no data but throws no compiler errors. Doesn't matter what the clock is adjusted to:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

flash.system.Security.allowDomain('*');

var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sample_auction.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);

var my_date:Date = new Date();
var currentHour:String = my_date.getUTCHours() +":" + my_date.getUTCMinutes();
trace(currentHour);



function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
xmlData = new XML(loader_ul.data);
var started:XMLList = xmlData.auction.(parseTime(time) < currentHour);
for each (var item:XML in started)
{
    auctionName_txt.text = item.title;
auctionDesc_txt.text = item.description;    
}       
}

function parseTime(time:String):Number {
var hour:int = time.split(":")[0];
var minute:int = time.split(":")[1];
return hour + minute / 60;
}
```

Comment: for(var i:uint = 0; i < xmlData.auction.length(); i++)
loop is not necessary. My example does not have it.

Comment: ok removed the loop - would the code then be: `for each (var item:XML in started)
    {
        auctionName_txt.text = xmlData.auction.title;
  auctionDesc_txt.text = xmlData.auction.description;  
    }`  to display? This produces the first node now instead of the last - it seems to do this because this first time is indeed < than current time - though setting the variable to == also produces the first node. Apologies if i'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: Nothing to apologize. Just copy fileLoaded function from my answer(I edited it one more time). Than you should answer to yourself: what time is in your XML("time" node value), UTC or local? Ones you answer, use one of the parseTime functions listed below. you can trace(item) in for each loop, to see what it really returns. BTW: since you have only two textFields - auctionName_txt and auctionDesc_txt, you will see only the last node values.

Comment: Thanks I think we are nearly there - I added up updated code above - let's say I'm using the UTC time from XML - so let's stick w that function (thank you for providing both!!) however now it returns no data when testing

Comment: Yes. I'm afraid but our comparison fails because we compare only time, and 24 june 09:00 appears to be earlier than 23 june 23:00. In order to compare time you should use new Date().getTime() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#time

Comment: Also I'm sorry for confusing you: var currentHour:String = my_date.getUTCHours() +":" + my_date.getUTCMinutes(); this line was for example only. You shouldn't change it and your currentHour should be like that: var currentHour:Number = my_date.getUTCHours() + my_date.getUTCMinutes() / 60;

Comment: I'm glad it finally works!)

Comment: final question ;) if I wanted to also display in a similar type text box, what the auction up next would be, would I accomplish this in a similar way but using a different comparison ?

Comment: I actually figured this out on my own here is the code: `function upNext(e:Event):void
{
    xmlData = new XML(next_ul.data);
    var started:XMLList = xmlData.auction.(parseTime(time) <= newHour);
    for each (var item:XML in started)
    {
        nextHour_txt.text = item.title;
    }       
}`

Comment: and: `var newHour:Number = currentHour + 1;
trace(newHour);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var my_date:Date = new Date();
var currentHour:String = my_date.getUTCHours() +":" + my_date.getUTCMinutes();
```

— You will get UTC time in HH:MM format.

```
trace(xml.auction.(time == currentHour))
```

Will trace node, which has "time" tag value == currentHour

---

But in your case we are comparing time.
Make sure you parse xml time value and cast it to Number right way.

Your *fileLoaded* function should look like this:

```
function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    xmlData = new XML(loader_ul.data);
    var started:XMLList = xmlData.auction.(parseTime(time) < currentHour);
    for each (var item:XML in started)
    {
        auctionName_txt.text = item.title;
        auctionDesc_txt.text = item.description; 
    }       
}
```

Also define *parseTime* function, **if your XML time is UTC**:

```
function parseTime(time:String):Number {
    var hour:int = time.split(":")[0];
    var minute:int = time.split(":")[1];
    return hour + minute / 60;
}
```

or if your **XML time** is your **local time**:

```
function parseTime(time:String):Number {
    var hour:int = time.split(":")[0];
    var minute:int = time.split(":")[1];
    var date:Date = new Date();
    date.setHours(hour);
    date.setMinutes(minute);
    return date.getUTCHours() + date.getUTCMinutes() / 60
}
```

Comment: So would that trace statement go in my "if" condition? Instead of what I have there now? How do I restrict the display of the data to the specific time period of the node (which is one hour) ?

Comment: apologies for multiple comments - so this pulls the data from the last node - if I place the trace statement into the if condition - it doesn't seem to matter what time I set the clock to it always pulls the same node. Anymore tips? :) :) :)

Comment: Is the parseTime function reliant on the UTC time? This seems to now display the first node rather than last, and strangely is showing the xml tags in the text displayed on the stage.. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: You are welcome. It is relevant to the time provided by XML, you should manually do comparison based on what data you receive. You can change comparison logic in this line: parseTime(time) < currentHour

Comment: i changed the logic to >= in the line that you said and it just runs to the last node of the XML no matter what - added the new code above

Comment: what would be the best way to make a countdown clock between the two hours? I have something like this: var timestamp:Number = getTimer();
var secondsLeft:Number = (getTimer() - timestamp)/1000;
trace(secondsLeft);  - but only returns 0 - can you help me?

Comment: google "AS3 timer". http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_the_timer_class_in_actio.html BTW: one question per topic please.

Comment: apologies for my noob - ness the topic can be found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557456/calculate-minutes-left-between-hours-actionscript-3)