# calculate minutes left between hours actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date, time, actionscript

I'm using AS3 to pull XML data, one field is a time field in the XML and displays an hour. I'm getting the date and then the AS3 loads the proper node based on teh time set in the XML. This is all working perfect - I have two times as variables, one is the system time (which is set in UTC time) the other is one hour ahead.

The two variables are currentHour and newHour - it's doing everything I want however I'd like to now create a countdown between these two hours and display time remaining in the minutes.

Here is the complete code for that. 
[Get the time from XML using AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533787/get-the-time-from-xml-using-as3)

These seems straight forward but I'm having a hard time. I've tried this:

```
var data:Array = [currentHour, newHour];

var aDate:String = data[0].split(" ")[0];

var dateElements:Array = aDate.split("-");
var date1:Date = new Date();
date1.setMinutes(int(data[0].split(" ")[1].split(":")[0]));
dateElements = data[1].split(" ")[0].split("-");
var date2:Date = new Date();
date2.setMinutes(int(data[1].split(" ")[1]));
var elapse:Number = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
trace("minutes: " + date2.getMinutes());
```

But that isn't right, so I tried this:

```
if(currentHour < newHour)
{
var dayDiff:Number = newHour-currentHour;
// make sure it’s in the future
if (dayDiff > 0)
{
var seconds:Number = dayDiff / 1000;
var minutes:Number = seconds / 60;
}
trace(minutes, seconds);
}
```

If someone could help me get unstuck that would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Some kind of output would be good so we know what the current status of the program is. What do you get traced in scenario #1 and in scenario #2?

Comment: Scenario 1 produces "TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
 at auction_test7_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()". Scenario two produces: 0.016666666666666666 as the trace result. Is always this regardless of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a new answer which didn't contain the spam from previous one where I tried to figure out what the actual issue was and what the expectations of the program was. Anyways to summarize:

User wanted to, given a specific date/time, find out how long until the next complete hour, so for instance given the time 4:47pm wanted to find out how many minutes and seconds left until 5:00pm.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.globalization.NumberFormatter;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.utils.Timer;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(250);
var my_date:Date = new Date();
var targetDate:Date = new Date();

//calculate how many total milliseconds left until next whole hour since that is how as3 is using Date-objects
var timeUntilWholeHourMS:Number = (60 - my_date.getMinutes()) * 60 * 1000;
targetDate.setTime(my_date.getTime() + timeUntilWholeHourMS);
//clear the "second and milliseconds" part of the new time since we want the whole hours
targetDate.setSeconds(0, 0);

var secondsLeft:Number = (targetDate.time - new Date().time) / 1000;
//make sure it is in the future
if (secondsLeft > 0) {
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
    timer.start();
}

function onTimer(e:flash.events.TimerEvent):void {
    secondsLeft = (targetDate.time - new Date().time)/1000;

    if (secondsLeft > 0) {
        var minutes:Number = Math.floor(secondsLeft/60);
        var seconds:Number = Math.floor(secondsLeft%60);
        trace("minutes left: " + minutes, ", seconds left: " + seconds);
    } else {
        //time limit reached
        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
        timer.stop();
        trace("Time limit reached!");
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems close but is about 2 minutes off - I really appreciate all your work here

Comment: Either your machines clock is wrong, or the servers clock is wrong. You can solve it either by setting your clock correctly or change the code to add 2 minutes of "ghost time".

Comment: this works - but it on refresh it seems to add a minute - I can add or subtract minutes but still seems off - do you think I could send you file ? It's like the rate is wrong - each refresh it changes the countdown amount in an inaccurate way.

Comment: I might be able to take a look tomorrow, provide a link to the file and I can look then. Now I need sleep. I don't know how you provide the "date (my_date)", you mentioned some xml file and whatnot. But that is the most likely candidate to be wrong. I experience no add of a minute, no matter how many time I start it etc. Maybe the provided date does not contain seconds meaning you'd be off somewhere between 0 and 59 seconds...

Comment: But you know, maybe you should check out and troubleshoot the last issue itself. The provided solution works and shows the correct amount of time left until whole hour. Also, unaccepting the answer... really? :(

Comment: so this is working - and actually I got it be perfectly accurate by adding: `targetDate.setMinutes(0, 0);` Now I just need it to restart on the hour! haha - would that be a simple else or else if statement for it restart the counter after a new hour is reached? - and I'm sorry I'm new to this forum so don't know how the answers work. I reaccepted - your answer - Thanks again for all your good work. I just need a way to reset the time at each hour change then we are golden. Thank you again!!!!! I appreciate everything.

Comment: Created a temp code site where you find an improved version that supports reset of time. http://pastebin.com/mdub7pP3

Comment: Wow this is nice. However when the time limit is reached the clock just Stops. This is still the case even after timer.stop(); is adjusted to timer.reset();

Comment: I've got a new mission if you chose to accept it!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687790/xml-as3-on-a-timer

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend you using Timer. At first declare a variable seconds (between currentHour and newHour):

```
private var seconds:int;
```

Then assign it value

```
seconds = (newHour - currentHour) * 3600;
```

Then declare a timer which will tick every second (second parameter tells how much times will it tick):

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, seconds)
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timer.start();
```

And then create timerHandler that will make all necessary updates:

```
function func(e:TimerEvent):void {
    --seconds;
    //if you have some textfield that shows minutes left, update it's text here
    //timeTextfieldText.text = int(seconds / 60) + " minutes left";
    trace(int(seconds / 60));
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work and will diverge away from the actual time since you assume that timer is EXACTLY 1000ms when it is "1000ms + any amount of time it takes to reach next frame".

Comment: Can you explain why this solution will not work? (it may have some diverge, but it works fine for me)

Comment: Created a small application using your solution at that time and have had it running until now. After 32689seconds your solution would report it as having being active for 32549seconds. The reason is that every time flash updates its' logic it checks if "time on timer is >= target time" and then updates and then resets timer. Meaning you will delay each 1000ms by a small margin. (My empiric study seems to suggest 1004ms)

Comment: Basically what you want to do is to save a timestamp at the initial time you started countdown from `var timestamp:Number = getTimer()` and then check against that whenever you need the time `var secondsLeft:Number = (getTimer() - timestamp)/1000;`

Comment: Daniel, do you think you can explain your solution further?

Comment: Hi Daniel - the output for your solution, if I trace secondsLeft, is 0. Can you clarify? (sorry thought i'd share output)

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear on how you want to present the data, but this is how to get it working at least. You need to replace "currentHour & newHour" with actual hours. And then handle the cases inside onTimer with approriate code.

The thing that differentiates this code towards the other solutions are that this takes a timestamp when you start and then whenever a timer event occurs it will check the current time against that timestamp. Meaning it doesn't matter if the flash timer is off by a couple of milliseconds etc.

```
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.globalization.NumberFormatter;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.utils.Timer;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(250);

var currentHour:Number = 14;
var newHour:Number = 15;
var totalSeconds:Number = 0;
var timestampStart:Number = 0;
if(currentHour < newHour) {
    totalSeconds = (newHour - currentHour) * 3600;
    if (totalSeconds > 0) {
        timestampStart = getTimer();
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
        timer.start();
    }
}

function onTimer(e:flash.events.TimerEvent):void {
    var secondsRunning:Number = (getTimer() - timestampStart) / 1000;
    var secondsLeft:Number = totalSeconds - secondsRunning;
    if (secondsLeft > 0) {
        var minutes:Number = Math.floor(secondsLeft/60);
        var seconds:Number = Math.floor(secondsLeft%60);
        trace("minutes left: " + minutes, ", seconds left: " + seconds);
    } else {
        //time limit reached
        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
        timer.stop();
        trace("Time limit reached!");
    }
}
```

Comment: So what I'm doing is showing time left on an auction. I simply want to show the time remaining from currentHour to the math.floor of the newHour. Make sense? So it would just be displaying a time left on this auction (for example) 12 minutes 43 seconds

Comment: it's essentially a 60 minute count down that needs to take into account the current time of the view of swf and calculate time remaining to the next whole hour.

Comment: well if you want it in minutes + seconds just convert secondsLeft to approriate formatting.

updated example to reflect that situation.

Comment: so the other issue is - currentHour and newHour can't be set a real number as they are being read in from XML.. will this still work? I appreciate the help here - and what is the 250? shouldn't that be 60 minutes? how would that look? - also I tested your's and just a countdown clock from where ever I set the timer to - what I need is to countdown from current time to next Hour. So if I view this at 2:45pm and the next auction is at 3pm then it would say 15 minutes and however many seconds left..

Comment: i created something like this to find the math.floor of newHour `var countDown:Number = Math.floor(newHour);
var timeLeft:Number = countDown - currentHour;
trace(timeLeft);`

Comment: I don't understand the problem. 250 is just an arbitary value of how many milliseconds before the timer should "tick" (call the event listener). In order to help with your issue. What is the format of the time that you have inside your program? Are they strings? Are they Date? Are they minutes? Seconds? Hours and Minutes and Seconds in a number format?

Comment: here is currentHour `var my_date:Date = new Date();
var currentHour:Number = my_date.getUTCHours() + (my_date.getUTCMinutes() / 60) + (my_date.getUTCSeconds() / 1000);
trace("current= " + currentHour);`

Comment: and newHour is being calculated like this (simply to pull the next hour node from the XML) `var newHour:Number = currentHour + 1;
trace(" future time= " + newHour);`

Comment: I don't understand your explanation... This is my understanding of what you want to do. You have 1 date that you somehow received from somewhere. That date is stored in var `my_date:Date`, which is a valid Date-object. Given that information, it seems like you want to have a countdown until 1 hour after that time. So if the date contains originally 04:57pm you want a countdown on how many minutes and seconds that are left until 05:57pm. Is that correct?

Comment: that's almost correct. If I have time 04:47pm I would want to count down to 5pm. The exact next hour. Not one hour from then.

Comment: Created a new answer since this one was solving the wrong problem

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an enterFrame event hanler

```
private var frameCount:int = 0;

private var diff:int = 3600;//the seconds between the two hours, you could set it here

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handler);

private function handler(event:Event):void {
     frameCount++;

     if (frameCount >= stage.frameRate) {

          frameCount = 0;

          diff--;

          if (diff < 0) {
              this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handler);
          }
     }

     var minutes:int = diff/60;
}
```

Comment: This is cool but anyway to do in the flash file and not have it dependent on a class file?

Comment: I tried this `var my_date:Date = new Date();
var currentHour:Number = my_date.getUTCHours() + (my_date.getUTCMinutes() / 60) + (my_date.getUTCSeconds() / 1000);
trace(currentHour);

var newHour:Number = currentHour + 1;
trace(newHour);

var displayTime:Number = newHour / 60;

var timestamp:Number = getTimer();
var secondsLeft:Number = (getTimer() - timestamp)/1000;
trace(secondsLeft);

var timeLeft:Number = displayTime - secondsLeft;
trace(timeLeft);`  but it's off..

Comment: your result will deviate away from the "actual time" as time passes on. Due to the fact that you are always relying on "last update" instead of the actual time between start and now (meaning that 1000 updates with 1ms off would put you one second off). Also, increasing cpu load would cause your solution to go out of sync significantly faster since you are relying on constant frame rate.